# Blackberry console output

Tags: blackberry, logging, java-me, console

I am new in black berry development, just like console output in J2me development and log cat in Android to see the event log of the simulator, is there anything for Blackberry so that I can keep a track on application logging on Blackberry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `System.out.println()` and it will appear in the output window in Eclipse. I would suggest putting some wrapper class around it to emulate some of the features of LogCat, such as making static methods that tag each with [DEBUG], [ERROR], stuff like that. Also, there will be a good bit of other debug output from the simulator/device, so find a way to distinguish your logs (I prepend ========== to each of them so I can see it quickly).

Comment: How do you make it appear in output window in eclipse? I deploy my app to device and then there is no connection between device and eclipse. Or I don't get something?

Comment: Either debug the app on device using Eclipse. Or create a blank app in Eclipse, and debug that on device using Eclipse. Both methods will create the link required, both methods will show you the output in the console.

Comment: I have the exact same problem that Mike stated above. There is no connection between eclipse and the device and i dont understand why. I right click on my project on eclipse , i hit debug as -> BB application , the application is deployed successfully , but i cant debug it in the console. The app just closes and when i open it again , its not connected to eclipse. Same happens with the simulator. Whatever i do it doesnt log anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @donparalias Not sure on that. May want to post it as a new question.

Answer (score 9):

We can use [System.out.println](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/lang/System.html#out) to print something to console.

Also we can use [EventLogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html) to log events to device system log (to view the current event log for the device, go to home screen hold down the ALT key and type "lglg"). Its more fun since we can filter logging by source and priority. Event log file also may be downloaded from device with command:

```
javaloader.exe -u eventlog > eventlog.txt
```

See [article about javaloader](http://www.enduserguides.com/mobile/blackberry/eug_bbjavaloader.html)

Also, consider to use some custom logging with [microlog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/microlog/) lib.