# BlackBerry - how to interpret sysout console output while debugging

Tags: debugging, blackberry

I'm having trouble chasing down a new bug in my BB app. I would like to gain understanding of the Console logging output that RIM provides.

**Background is**: I can't get it to break on simulator, so am running a JDE-4.5-compiled app on a Torch device. Using on-device debugging through Eclipse (on Windows).

Some minutes into running the app, I can get it to crash - there are lots of web service calls happening all the time, with lots of UI updates to rows in a list. When the app crashes, Eclipse does not catch the exception.

I have inspected the system log (`ALT-lglg`) but there are really a lot of messages in there, mostly referring to the message/event loop. However, I can find no reference to my code in them. I will further investigate the log (having downloaded it thanks to Max Gontar on [Blackberry console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439331/blackberry-console-output)). However, with this current post I am asking more about the interpretation of the console output, rather than general BB debugging tips.

The output on crash is the regular popup box saying:

> Uncaught exception: Application ITrack(307) is not
>   responding; process terminated

---

**Question is**: How do I interpret the attached console output - specifically I feel that the `VM:...` lines might hold some useful info, but I can find no resources with Google on their meaning?

Below the console output (separated with comments from what I already understand):

-My debug output - web service complete, JSON logged. Previous lines on console are almost all similar to this - this is the app running correctly:

```
Response received: 5
{"lng":"28.256607055664063","lat":"-25.828020095825195","zip_postal":"","city":"Pretoria","town":"Pretoria","road":"Alandale Street","suburb":"Elardus Park","region":"Gauteng","country":"South Africa"}
response success: 5
```

-**CRASH!!!**:

```
VM:ECTTv=1,w=0
Application ITrack(307) is not responding; process terminated
```

-These lines are somehow related to one of the errors - I see them duplicated in the device log:

```
[0 2]
0 2
```

-<SNIP> - 0 2 gets repeated 62(!) times:

```
0 2
3d 3501
0 2
0 2
0 2
0 2
3d 3502
0 2
```

-<SNIP> - 0 2 gets repeated another 31 times:

-This part gives some info on the Objects that are being used as Thread locks at the time of the crash. **More info is required.**

```
VM:THMNx=177,r=0x19965800,t=java.lang.Object
VM:THMNx=147,r=0x19966400,t=net.rim.vm.Message
VM:THMNx=177,r=0x20AC00,t=CHAR[]
VM:THMNx=147,r=0x197CD000,t=net.rim.vm.MessageQueue
VM:THMNx=138,r=0x228D8800,t=net.rim.device.cldc.io.proxyhttp.ClientProtocol
VM:THMNx=129,r=0x22718C00,t=net.rim.device.cldc.io.proxyhttp.ClientProtocol
```

-This part I know nothing about.

```
VM:THDRr=native
VM:THDLv=0
VM:ECTTv=0,w=0
```

-App has crashed, system is cleaning up and returning to Home Ribbon screen:

```
AM: Exit ITrack(307)
ApplicationManagerImpl.processExited : process process switching to background:  pid=307
Process ITrack(307) cleanup started
Process ITrack(307) cleanup done
AM: Foreground is requested: net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(109)
TID:unable to execute in the app com.mix.ITrack.main.Application@1a29405e|java.lang.Object@7fbc2b0a|-1
FocusHistory: Focus gained; App ITrack; Component com.mix.ITrack.shared.mix.ui.controls.DynamicRowListField
FocusHistory: Focus lost; App ITrack; Component net.rim.device.apps.internal.ribbon.launcher.ApplicationAreaGridField
FocusHistory: Focus gained; App net_rim_bb_ribbon_app; Component net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField
AM: Foreground is set: net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(109)
ApplicationManagerImpl.setForegroundProcess : calling notifyApplicationSwitch to switch to foreground: process=net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(109) pid=109
```

---

- Is there any info in here that looks useful to someone with more experience on BB than I have?
- Has anyone any info on interpreting the `VM:...` lines?

(Please note I am not asking for general BB debugging advice, as there are already some great answers on stackoverflow about that. However I would love to this 'mysterious' RIM logging code.)

Answer (score 1):

to start off: according to [this BlackBerry forum answer by klyubin](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Application-is-crashing/m-p/217877#M32299), the lines starting with `VM:THMNx=` refer to the locks being held at the time of the crash.