# How to see logs in blackberry device?

Tags: logging, blackberry, qr-code

I am using ZXing 1.7 library for creating Barcode Sanner for Blackberry device.

In that they have used their own class of Log. 
But how can I see what I have Logged using Log.info(" Test ")?

Can I see that on the device?

Answer (score 3):

Method `Log.info(String)` is in class `com.google.zxing.client.rim.util.Log`.

Class logs to the `net.rim.device.api.system.EventLogger`. If you have the source code, you can change the code to also log to `System.out`. Below is a block of code copied from the source, with my change to set the logging output to `System.out`:

```
  /** Used to determine if the log message should be set to System.out */
  private static final boolean logToSystemOut;

  static {
   // Initializes the logger. Currently set to not log to System.out and log
   // at the INFO level.
    EventLogger.register(LOG_ID_LONG, LOG_ID_STRING, EventLogger.VIEWER_STRING);
    EventLogger.setMinimumLevel(EventLogger.DEBUG_INFO); // set this to change logging level message.

    logToSystemOut = true; // <-- UPDATE THIS LINE TO SET TO true
  }
```

With this change, you can view the output in the Debug window of Eclipse, when the app is running. To make it easier to find (cos there is so much info in this console), I would make this change:

```
  private static void logToSystemOut(String message) {
    if (logToSystemOut) {
      System.out.println("  ------------ " + message);
    }
  }
```

---

The other way is to view the `EventLogger` output directly. On device you can do this by following instructions from the EventLogger javadoc:

- *To view the current event log for the device, hold down the ALT key and type "lglg".*

Alternatively, you can download the event log onto your PC using the [javaloader](http://www.enduserguides.com/mobile/blackberry/eug_bbjavaloader.html) tool:

- `javaloader.exe -u eventlog > eventlog.txt`

---

For more info about this, see this question: [Blackberry console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439331/blackberry-console-output). I have copied some info in the answers from there.

Comment: for Blackberry there is a Java file naming ZXingLMMainScreen in which u'll find number statements which are Like Log.info(""); If I want to see those logs how can I see that on device or on PC?

Comment: in ZXing 1.7 you'll find code for Blackberry that is rim. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-1.7.zip&can=2&q=