# How to output blackberry webworks console.log() to a file?

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-webworks

I am using IBM Worklight framework to develop iOS and blackberry applications. In my javascript code there are hundreds of lines of "console.log()". In iOS, we managed to log these into a log file. But in blackberry webworks application i am unable to find a way to put these messages in a log file on the phone.

I have read the web inspector but it does not meet my requirements. I am using blackberry version 6.

Comment: Worklight Version: 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- to access the device log screen by holding the ALT key while pressing LGLG?
- you may also try using [BlackBerry's EventLogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html)
- also see the following question, which mentions (in the unaccepted answer) how to export the log file: [Blackberry console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439331/blackberry-console-output)

Comment: Using EventLogger, I am able to log java messages but the messages I logged using javascript console.debug() are not displayed in the EventLog. I am using ALT+LGLG to view the log. I do see some messages auto produced by Worklight "app:LoggerWorklight" but my custom console.debug are not appearing.